# Export Excel Sheet dropdown option limits

Tags: excel, laravel, import, export-to-excel

I want to export Excel sheet with add drop down option multiple fields. for this I am using below but issue is that when I add more then 15 drop down option excel sheet does not export properly. this show error (attached screenshot). if option in less then 15 its working fine. is there any limit of add drop down option in export excel sheet programmatically.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductSampleExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings,WithEvents

{
protected  $selects;
protected  $row_count;
protected  $column_count;

public function __construct()

{
    $pcats = Category::select('name')->where('parent_id',0)->get();
    $status=array();
    $departments = array();
    foreach($pcats as $pcat){
        $status[] = $pcat->name;
    }
    $scats = Category::select('name')->where('parent_id','!=',0)->limit(15)->get();
    //$scats = Category::select('name')->where('parent_id','!=',0)->limit(20)->get();
  
    foreach($scats as $scat){
        $departments[] = str_replace('-','',$scat->name);
    }
    // dd($departments);
    // $status=['active','pending','disabled'];
    // $departments=['Account','Admin','Ict','Sales'];
    // $departments=ModelName::pluck('name')->toArray(); You can get values from a model or DB Facade
    $selects=[  //selects should have column_name and options
        ['columns_name'=>'C','options'=>$departments], //Column D has heading departments. See headings() method below
        ['columns_name'=>'E','options'=>$status],
    ];

    $this->selects=$selects;
    $this->row_count=50;//number of rows that will have the dropdown
    $this->column_count=5;//number of columns to be auto sized
}
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function collection()


{      
    return collect([]);
}


public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'name', //column A
        'email', //column B
        'phone', //column C
        'department', //column D
        'status', //column E
        'role', //column F
    ];
}

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        // handle by a closure.
        AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $row_count = $this->row_count;
            $column_count = $this->column_count;
            foreach ($this->selects as $select){
                $drop_column = $select['columns_name'];
                $options = $select['options'];
                // set dropdown list for first data row
                $validation = $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_column}2")->getDataValidation();
                $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                $validation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"',implode(',',$options)));

                // clone validation to remaining rows
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_column}{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
                }
                // set columns to autosize
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $column_count; $i++) {
                    $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
                    $event->sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            }
        },
    ];
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found out the answer DataValidation::TYPE_LIST has a character limit of 255 that's why it's working with 15 option and stop working when I add more option because the character limit exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

As Mayukh Bhattacharya mentioned in his comment, there is a 255 char limit. You can get around this however by using the WithMultipleSheets interface, and placing the options for each select in a separate column, and each option on its respective columns rows.

Then, you can reference the sheet and row range
Example:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Exports\Excel\CatalogItem\Sheets;

    use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

    class ExampleExport implements FromView, WithTitle, 
    {
    public function setDropDown(
        string $column,
        Worksheet $sheet,
        int $startRow,
        string $sheetName,
        ?string $formula = '!$A$2:$A$10000',
        ?int $endRow = null,
        ?bool $showErrors = true,
        ?bool $allowBlank = true,
    ): static
    {
        $list = '\'' . $sheetName . '\'' . $formula;
        if (strlen($list) > 253) {
            throw new Exception('Excel only allows 255 total characters for static validation lists');
        }

        $startCell = $column . $startRow;
        $endRow = $endRow ?? $sheet->getHighestRow();
        $endCell = $column . $endRow; //specified large number to include all cells up to

        $validation = $sheet->getCell($startCell)->getDataValidation();
        $validation->setType( DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
        $validation->setErrorStyle( DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
        $validation->setAllowBlank($allowBlank);
        $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
        $validation->setShowErrorMessage($showErrors);
        $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
        $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
        $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
        $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
        $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');

        $validation->setFormula1($list);

        $validation->setSqref("{$startCell}:{$endCell}");

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet) : void
    {
        parent::styles($sheet);
        $this->setDropDown(column: 'A', sheet: $sheet, startRow: 2, sheetName: 'Options', endRow: 10000);
    }      

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        return 'Export';
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return 'some.blade.php';
    }
}
```